# why class to style in react js, why not ID?

Tags: reactjs

why generally we only use class to style the components in react js, why not ID?
As we are using class & ID in normal javascript.

Comment: In ReactJS we use components right? which can be reused and we also know that IDs can not be reused thus we go for classes. But you can target a particular element it's not like we can not use Id's.

Answer (score 2):

you can render one component multiple times on the page, this will result in multiple elements with the same id and leads to unpredictable errors